# sql oracle: get null values when type does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `phone` with those values

```
emplid  type    phone
1       HOME    23452
2       HOME    15284
2       BUSN    25523
3       HOME    26542
```

I want for each emplid his HOME and BUSN phone. When he has no BUSN phone it has to be null. So my result has to be:

```
emplid  type    phone
1       HOME    23452
2       HOME    15284
2       BUSN    25523
3       HOME    26542
1       BUSN    null
3       BUSN    null
```

I tried to join with a dummy table

```
(select 'HOME'as typ from dual
                union select 'HOM2' from dual )
```

but it does not give me the desired result. I don't know how I can join it with my `phone` table

Comment: Did you really try to join with a dummy table where the second value is 'HOM2', when you are trying to get 'BUSN' instead? I see no reason why that would work, regardless of anything else.

Comment: Also, do you have a table `phone` with a column `phone` in it? This may not violate any formal rules, but it will almost surely lead to confusion (and bugs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many versions ago, Oracle introduced **partitioned** outer join just for this kind of problem. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW0072

You do need a table with the various types that need to be included. Or, as you were trying to do, you can create it on the fly. IN ADDITION, you need the "partition" clause to the outer join. It is shown in ALL CAPS in the code below (so that it can be found easily).

As a separate and unrelated thing, in the "helper" subquery that I create to substitute for an actual "types" table I also create an ORD column, to use for ordering. This is only needed if you want to always show the HOME number before the BUSN number in the main query. Of course, there are other ways to achieve the same outcome, but since we are creating a helper subquery anyway, we get this at essentially no additional cost.

```
with
  phone(emplid, type, phone) as (
    select 1, 'HOME', 23452 from dual union all
    select 2, 'HOME', 15284 from dual union all
    select 2, 'BUSN', 25523 from dual union all
    select 3, 'HOME', 26542 from dual
  )
-- end of sample data (for testing only, not part of the actual query)
select p.emplid, h.type, p.phone
from   (
         select 'HOME' as type, 1 as ord from dual union all
         select 'BUSN'        , 2        from dual
       ) h
       left outer join phone p  PARTITION BY (EMPLID)
       on h.type = p.type
order by p.emplid, h.ord     
;

    EMPLID TYPE      PHONE
---------- ---- ----------
         1 HOME      23452
         1 BUSN           
         2 HOME      15284
         2 BUSN      25523
         3 HOME      26542
         3 BUSN
```

Comment: Perfect. I changed a little, to get all possible types like this: https://rextester.com/NXUF8115

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all possible `emplid` values and cross-join with all possible `type` values, and then see which ones actually exist using an outer join.

For example, if you want to base this entirely on other data in your `phone` table you could get the distinct values for the first two columns using inline views:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with phone (emplid, type, phone) as (
  select 1, 'HOME', 23452 from dual
  union all select 2, 'HOME', 15284 from dual
  union all select 2, 'BUSN', 25523 from dual
  union all select 3, 'HOME', 26542 from dual
)
-- actual query
select e.emplid, t.type, p.phone
from (select distinct emplid from phone) e
cross join (select distinct type from phone) t
left join phone p on p.emplid = e.emplid and p.type = t.type;

    EMPLID TYPE      PHONE
---------- ---- ----------
         1 HOME      23452
         2 HOME      15284
         2 BUSN      25523
         3 HOME      26542
         3 BUSN           
         1 BUSN
```

But you might really want to get the possible `emplid` values from, say, an employee table - in which case you'd see null values for all employees even if they had no phone records at all; and you might want to get the possible `type` values from some other table, or hard-code the list:

```
select e.emplid, t.type, p.phone
from (select distinct emplid from phone) e -- or more likely from a separate employee table
cross join (select 'HOME' as type from dual union all select 'HOM2' from dual) t
left join phone p on p.emplid = e.emplid and p.type = t.type;

    EMPLID TYPE      PHONE
---------- ---- ----------
         1 HOME      23452
         2 HOME      15284
         3 HOME      26542
         1 HOM2           
         2 HOM2           
         3 HOM2
```

I've stuck with the `'HOM2'` value you used, even though that wasn't in your sample data at all; but as you can see you get null entries for that name for all employee IDs too.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried was the correct method though. Just another table

```
SELECT PhoneTypes.EmplID, PhoneTypes.Type, Phone
FROM Phone
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Distinct emplid, T.Type FROM Phone, (select 'HOME' FROM DUAL as type union select 'HOM2' FROM DUAL union select 'BUSN' FROM DUAL) T) PhoneTypes
   ON Phone.type=PhoneTypes.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I think it is similar to your approach

```
select t.* from Phone t
left outer join 
(
  select 'HOME'as typ from dual
  union select 'HOM2' from dual ) t2
on typ = type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with 
phone as (
    select 1 as emplid, 'HOME' as type, '23452' as phone from dual union
    select 2, 'HOME', '15284' from dual union
    select 2,'BUSN','25523' from dual union
    select 3,'HOME','26542' from dual),
types as (
    select distinct type from phone 
    )
select phone.emplid, types.type, phone.phone 
 from types
  left join phone partition by (emplid)
      on phone.type = types.type
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using the logic with `not in`

```
with phone(emplid, type, phone) as 
(
 select 1, 'HOME', 23452 from dual union all
 select 2, 'HOME', 15284 from dual union all
 select 2, 'BUSN', 25523 from dual union all
 select 3, 'HOME', 26542 from dual
)
select * from phone
union all
select emplid, 'BUSN', null 
  from phone
 where emplid not in 
       ( select emplid 
           from phone p 
          where type = 'BUSN'
            and p.emplid = emplid );

EMPLID  TYPE    PHONE
------  ----    -----
1       HOME    23452
2       HOME    15284
2       BUSN    25523
3       HOME    26542
3       BUSN    NULL
1       BUSN    NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/VWZ69926)</kbd>

Comment: This wouldn't help if an employee only has a business number but no home number; one can speculate that in that case the OP would want to show HOME number as NULL too.